# OpenLayers 3 and Three.js

Tags: openlayers, wms, three-js

I have asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501473/terrain-floor-and-openlayer-map) in StackOverflow, but got no useful answer - So perhaps I could get some help here.

I would like to generate a 3d Terrain using THREE.js, and I would like to overlay OpenLayers upon it. Does anyone know how to do it?

EDIT: 
I tried this (based on [this](http://turban.github.io/webgl-terrain/wxs/jotunheimen.html))

```
var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(60, 100, 100),material2);
scene.add(sphere2);
sphere2.position = new THREE.Vector3(100,230,140);
var material3= new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
material3.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=basic&CRS=epsg:4326&BBOX=-90,-180,90,180&WIDTH=500&HEIGHT=500&FORMAT=image/png');
```

This should generate a sphere, and map the texture as returned by the WMS call to the sphere, making a full earth - but it does not load anything - the screen remains black.

Comment: lol, I remember that question, and in fact commented on it, it would seem. You cannot overlay OpenLayers upon anything -- it is a library, not a datasource. You will be able to do the opposite though, especially once 3d support is more developed. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I can generate hightmaps as mesh, but when I do not know how to display a canvas / context on an openlayers map.

Answer (score 1):

There is question titled [Geographic rasters in three.js scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509799/geographic-rasters-in-three-js-scene) at Stack Overflow that refers to loading a tile from WMS and using it as a texture in THREE.js.

You can request a WMS tile by sending a complete wms request url with bounds, etc. This is covered in [this answer by @iant](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115912/displaying-a-geoserver-map-from-a-java-mobile-application/115916#115916) to a question on [Displaying a GeoServer Map from a Java Mobile Application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115912/displaying-a-geoserver-map-from-a-java-mobile-application).

Comment: please see update

Answer (score 1):

You have not written  it right ......
try this one....

```
var geo_earth = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 32, 32);
var txtr_earth = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../api/proxy/getmap');
var mat_earth = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: txtr_earth}); 

var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(geo_earth, mat_earth);
scene.add(sphere2);
```

I used a proxy to server my image because the request was insecure.