# Return Image from WMS service

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, terrain

I asked this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118899/ol3-and-three-js?noredirect=1#comment168924_118899), and I realize that I am going in the wrong direction.

I would like to do this :

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry(); 
// push vertices here
var some_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(SOME_MAGIC_FUNCTION_TO_RETURN_A_SINGLE IMAGE_FROM_WMS_TILES(lat_bounds,long_bounds))
      });
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, some_material)
```

Can I use Openlayers / Leaflet?

I do not see how I could do this, immediately from their documentations.

I seek to construct / use the `SOME_MAGIC_FUNCTION_TO_RETURN_A_SINGLE IMAGE_FROM_WMS_TILES(lat_bounds,long_bounds)`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't play with it but I remember seeing Bjørn Sandvik from Thematic Mapping playing with Three.js and WMS.

The recipe is available on [this blog post](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2014/03/using-web-map-services-with-threejs.html).

Comment: Hi, tried that, with this code : `var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(60, 100, 100),material2);
scene.add(sphere2);
sphere2.position = new THREE.Vector3(100,230,140);
var material3= new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
material3.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=basic&CRS=epsg:4326&BBOX=-90,-180,90,180&WIDTH=500&HEIGHT=500&FORMAT=image/png');`

It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in [THIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115912/displaying-a-geoserver-map-from-a-java-mobile-application/115916#115916) answer which asks how to return a tile for a Java Application.

You can load a single tile by sending a completely formatted WMS url which includes the bounds that you want. See the answer from *iant* for more details.